# Remove rows in matrix where column equals any value in vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix `A` that is size `967874 x 3` and a vector `v` that is length `7211`.

I want to create a new matrix `B` that equals matrix `A` minus all the rows in `A` where the 2nd column value equals any of the elements in `v`.

What's a fast way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B = A(~ismember(A(:,2), v), :)
```